# Can I move Paypal button to checkout page in magento?

Tags: magento, paypal

Is there any way to move Paypal button to checkout page, anyone can help with this?

Comment: you want to change the order or remove paypal button?

Comment: I want to put paypal button with other payment methods? is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Each payment method has a field named Sort Order. Starting at one, place a number in each enabled payment method, save and they should appear in the cart payment section in the order you entered.

```
System => Configuration => Sales => Payment Methods
```

for more help, check [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-up-paypal-payments-standard-for-magento-community)

Answer (score 0):

Paypal express checkout button is on cart page.

Paypal standard module if used will show Paypal button on checkout page.

So suggestion is that you enable paypal standard.

Comment: I Enabled Payal standard and it still doesent show in checkout page, anything else i should do?